# How to split test and train size

Tags: python, tensorflow, testing, scikit-learn

I am trying to feed a CNN model(Human body pose estimation)with a dataset contains 1000 numbers,
first, how can I make sure that the number of my datasets is already enough?
second, how should i split my data to train and test size? (when I put train size = 0.6 and test_size = 0.4 the network doesnt work well and show me NAN for weights and bias and loss value!)

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed way to determine when you have a sufficient size data set. It depends on many factors. Best thing to do is run with what you have and see how it performs. I usually split my data into 3 sets, training, validation and test. I usually try 75% for training, 15% for validation and 10% for final test.The validation set is what I use to tweek the hyper parameters. Initially I monitor the training accuracy and loss. If I can get that up to over 95% then I monitor the validation accuracy and loss. I use the model_checkpoint keras callback to save the model with the lowest validation loss. If the validation accuracy and loss is not satisfactory I tweek the hyper parameters to try to improve it. I have found using an adjustable learning rate to be useful for this purpose. Finally when I am satisfied with the training accuracy and validation accuracy I use the saved model to make predictions on the test set. This is the final measure of how the model performs.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. You did really help~